# How to root and what apps to use

Tags: applications, rooting, htc-droid-incredible-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I root my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device)

I have an HTC Incredible 2. I would like to know how to remove the locked pre installed apps and what apps I need for longer battery life and to maximize memory. (cpu not storage.)

My device is S-ON by the way. I know that makes it more difficult at the least, but if there is a way I would like to know.

Answer (score -2):

Try this: http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/dfy5x/all_how_to_root_your_android_phone/

Comment: Answer that are nothing but links to other sites are not generally considered helpful, if for no other reason than should that link go away the answer becomes worse than useless.